# How to use Spring Data Near and Within Query Keywords?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I came across the following snipped in a [Spring sample](https://github.com/olivergierke/rest-microservices/blob/master/store-service/src/main/java/example/stores/StoreRepository.java):

```
public interface StoreRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Store, UUID> {

@RestResource(rel = "by-location")
Page<Store> findByAddressLocationNear(//
        @Param("location") Point location, @Param("distance") Distance distance, Pageable pageable);}
```

I want to achieve a similar thing with my entities `Shop` and `Address`:

```
@Entity
public class Shop {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Getter @Setter
private long id;

@Getter @Setter
private String title;

@Getter @Setter
private String description;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "shop")

@Getter @Setter
private List<Discount> discounts;

@OneToOne
@Getter @Setter
private Address address;


}

@Entity
public class Address {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Getter @Setter
private long id;

@Getter @Setter
private Point location;

@Getter @Setter
private String street;

@Getter @Setter
private String city;

@Getter @Setter
private String zip;

}
```

How would the spring data repository query method look like to find `Shops` near a given `location`?

I tried `List<Shop> findByAddressLocationNear(Point address_location, Distance d);` but this doesn't work. I assume that I need either the `Near` or `Within` keyword.

Comment: Maybe this example will be helpful https://github.com/mstahv/spring-boot-spatial-example ...